# SQL statement for a login from a database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a login page with a UserName field and a PassCode field for an ASP.Net web page, I feel I am close. Please help.

```
Protected Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM loginInfo"
    Dim sqlUser As String = "SELECT DISTINCT UserName FROM loginInfo"
    Dim sqlPass As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PassCode FROM loginInfo"

    con = New OleDbConnection( _
      "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("DynamicDataBase.mdb"))


    If txtUserName.Text = sqlUser And txtPassCode.Text = sqlPass Then
        Response.Redirect("gridView.aspx")

    End If

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What error messages / exceptions are you getting?  Without knowing what's wrong, it's hard to offer any help.

Comment: A suggestion - you should take the username and password, and check that specific combination in your DB, all in one query. Use a `WHERE`

Comment: You haven't actually executed any queries.  Therefore, you are comparing the user entered username to the string "SELECT DISTINCT UserName FROM loginInfo".

Comment: sorry, I am trying to get it to compare to the datatbase table loginInfo and redireect, but its not rediecting.

Comment: To shree.pat18, How would you write that in one query? _                      __ "SELECT UserName, PassCode From loginInfo Where "[txtUserName.Text and txtPassCode.Text] = "UserName" and "PassCode"

Comment: Remember to **hash** and **salt** the password!

Answer (score 1):

Validating User Credentials from DB:

```
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=  C:\Users\data\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Registration_form.mdb";
string cmdText = "select Count(*) from Login where Username=? and [Password]=?"
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
{
     con.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtlognUsrnm.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtlognpswrd.Text);  
     int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()
     con.Close();
     if(result > 0)
          Response.Redirect("gridView.aspx")
     else
         lblMsg.Text="Failed to Login"
}
```

**NOTE:** Get the `Connection string` from `config` file.